# How enable watchdog?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, watchdog

I'm struggling with the watchdog timer (wdt) for a while. I can't get it working.

My microcontroller is a AriaG25, based on the AT91SAM925. I have used [this tutorial](http://www.acmesystems.it/ariag25_compile_linux_2_6_39) to compile the kernel. The kernel settings related to the wdt looks like this:

```
CONFIG_WATCHDOG=y       
CONFIG_AT91SAM9X_WATCHDOG=y
```

The kernel has been compiled without problem and boots succesfully. I've installed the watchdog deamon software via `apt-get`. And now I'm stuck. How do I get the watchdog working? I read a lot about `/dev/watchdog`. I don't have that file.  Do I have to put the driver for my hardware there? Is [this](http://sg.danny.cz/foxg20/ariag25/380rc3/ariag25.dts) a driver?

Comment: Have you looked at the watchdog man page? http://linux.die.net/man/8/watchdog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've changed my kernel configuration to this:

```
CONFIG_WATCHDOG=y
CONFIG_SOFT_WATCHDOG=m
CONFIG_AT91SAM9X_WATCHDOG=y
```

Now my watchdog timer was running. I only had to edit `/etc/watchdog.conf` in order to set up tests.

Comment: To make the best of the watchdog protection you may also need to configure the daemon to run tests that verify your system's critical operation(s) are working. I have been doing this for our control computers and documented it [here](http://www.sat.dundee.ac.uk/~psc/watchdog/Linux-Watchdog.html)