# DMP 3300MX-A embedded pc, debian 6.0 squeeze, kernel 3.2, bios watchdog and harwdare reset

Tags: debian, embedded, bios, watchdog

I have been studying how to properly set up a watchdog on my embedded system, have read plenty of posts, but I am stuck with no solution.
I've read:

- [How to correctly configure Debian watchdog daemon for BIOS Watch Dog?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64057/how-to-correctly-configure-debian-watchdog-daemon-for-bios-watch-dog)
- [What is a "watchdog reset"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21338/what-is-a-watchdog-reset?rq=1)
- [How do I cause a watchdog reset of my embedded Linux device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21335/how-do-i-cause-a-watchdog-reset-of-my-embedded-linux-device?rq=1)
- [How enable watchdog?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88527/how-enable-watchdog)

I even gave a deep look at

- http://www.sat.dundee.ac.uk/~psc/watchdog/Linux-Watchdog.html

but no way out at this moment.

So I will start describing my hardware/software and explaining what I am trying to achieve, then I will explain what I did and what was the result. Hoping that someone of you can point me out to the right direction.

**Harwdare**:

a DMP embedded with Vortex86DX cpu (A9111 @ 933Mhz), see some documentation at the following addresses:

- http://www.dmp.com.tw/tech/vortex86dx/#feature2
- http://www.dmp.com.tw/tech/vortex86dx/img/Vortex86DX_block_internal.jpg

This has harwdare support for 2 watchdog timers (16C550 Serial Port 1, GPIO Port 4) with ALI (Acer Labs) M6117 watchdog hardware, a 32.768KHz clock with a 24 bits counter. The timer ranges is from 30.5u sec to 512 sec with resolution 30.5u sec. When the timer times out; a system reset, NMI or IRQ may happen.

**BIOS**:

American Megatrends AMIBIOS (62-0100-000001-00101111-110309-A9100-1ADSV000-Y2KC), bios date 08/03/2011

**OS**:

Debian 6.0 squeeze with linux kernel (# uname -r) 3.2.0-0.bpo.4-486

**Driver**:

ALI M6117 watchdog v0.2 given to me directly by the manufacturer that states that it can be used with my kernel, and which is based on Federico Bareilles original driver for linux 2.4.x (http://www.iar.unlp.edu.ar/~fede/ali_m6117.html)

**My goal:**

Since this machine is installed far from where I live, and sometimes it freezes, I am forced to take my car and go there to do an hardware reset.

***I would like to set it up so that when the system freezes, the machine is able to reset itself.***

**What I've done:**

I've compiled the above driver (make clean, make) and I've installed it (make install). The module is properly found in the "extra" folder under the kernel path.

I've edited `/etc/watchdog.conf` file and uncommented the line `/dev/watchdog` to enable the watchdog (and nothing else, no other lines uncommented or added)

I've moved to the /lib/modules/3.2.0-0.bpo.4-486/extra folder and loaded the module with `insmod alim6117_wdt.ko`

Checked that the module was loaded with`lsmod` and I got

```
Module alim6117_wdt, size 12565, used by 0
```

(this becomes 1 when I enable the watchdog in the BIOS)

Rebooted the machine, entered the BIOS and enabled watchdog 0, watchdog 0 timer 512sec, watchdog 0 signal select "reset"

*What I've got:*

The system boots up properly,I see the messages about the watchdog being enabled/loaded, but after a bit it reboots with the message
`alim6117_wdt unexpected close, not stopping watchdog`

If I run `dmesg | watchdog` I get `[0.017827] NMI watchdog disabled (cpu0): hardware events not enabled`, but I think this is not important since all I need is an hardware reset.

I've made a further test, without succeeding, by adding to the `/etc/watchdog.conf` file the following lines:

```
ping            = 127.00.0.1
interface       = lan0
```

`lan0` is the proper name of the ethernet interface, obtained with `ifconfig` command. Or should I use `lo` as interface since I am trying to ping the `loopback` interface?

Just in case of any help, the last messages I see when the system completes its boot are:

```
stopping watchdog keepalive daemon....
stargint watchdog daemon....
startpar: service(s) returnet failure: rc.local ... failed!
```

In the boot sequence, at a certain point, the watchdog keepalive daemon gets started, then it gets stopped right after starting the watchdog daemon. Is this an odd thing? Or is it normal? Should the wd_keepalive stay always on or it is supposed to go down when the watchdog daemon goes up? (I've investigated this a bit and, if I understand, it seems to be normal, so I am a bit confused)

This is becoming a thorn in my side.
What am I doing wrong? Could someone point me to the right direction?

Following is the source code of the driver

```
 /** 
 *   ALi M6117 Watchdog timer driver.
 *
 *   (c) Copyright 2003 Federico Bareilles <fede@fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar>,
 *   Instituto Argentino de Radio Astronomia (IAR).
 *
 *   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 *   modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as
 *   published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of
 *   the License, or (at your option) any later version.
 *     
 *   The author does NOT admit liability nor provide warranty for any
 *   of this software. This material is provided "AS-IS" in the hope
 *   that it may be useful for others.
 *
 *   Based on alim1535_wdt.c by Alan Cox and other WDT by several
 *   authors...
 *
 *   ALi (Acer Labs) M6117 is an i386 that has the watchdog timer
 *   built in.  Watchdog uses a 32.768KHz clock with a 24 bits
 *   counter. The timer ranges is from 30.5u sec to 512 sec with
 *   resolution 30.5u sec. When the timer times out; a system reset,
 *   NMI or IRQ may happen. This can be decided by the user's
 *   programming.
 **/

#define ALI_WDT_VERSION "0.2.0"

#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/miscdevice.h>
#include <linux/watchdog.h>
#include <asm/io.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/reboot.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>

#define OUR_NAME "alim6117_wdt"

/* Port definitions: */
#define M6117_PORT_INDEX 0x22
#define M6117_PORT_DATA  0x23
/* YES, the two unused ports of 8259:
 * 0020-003f : pic1 
 *
 * The 8259 Interrup Controller uses four port addresses (0x20 through
 * 0x23). Although IBM documentation indicates that these four port
 * addresses are reserved for the 8259, only the two lower ports (0x20
 * and 0x21) ar documented as usable by programers. The two ports
 * (0x22 and 0x23) are used only when reprogramming the 8259 for
 * special dedicated systems that operate in modes which are not
 * compatible with normal IBM PC operation (this case).
 **/

/* Index for ALI M6117: */
#define ALI_LOCK_REGISTER 0x13
#define ALI_WDT           0x37
#define ALI_WDT_SELECT    0x38
#define ALI_WDT_DATA0     0x39
#define ALI_WDT_DATA1     0x3a
#define ALI_WDT_DATA2     0x3b
#define ALI_WDT_CTRL      0x3c

/* Time out generates signal select: */
#define WDT_SIGNAL_IRQ3  0x10
#define WDT_SIGNAL_IRQ4  0x20
#define WDT_SIGNAL_IRQ5  0x30
#define WDT_SIGNAL_IRQ6  0x40
#define WDT_SIGNAL_IRQ7  0x50
#define WDT_SIGNAL_IRQ9  0x60
#define WDT_SIGNAL_IRQ10 0x70
#define WDT_SIGNAL_IRQ11 0x80
#define WDT_SIGNAL_IRQ12 0x90
#define WDT_SIGNAL_IRQ14 0xa0
#define WDT_SIGNAL_IRQ15 0xb0
#define WDT_SIGNAL_NMI   0xc0
#define WDT_SIGNAL_SRSET 0xd0
/* set signal to use: */
#define WDT_SIGNAL       WDT_SIGNAL_SRSET

/* ALI_WD_TIME_FACTOR is 1000000/30.5 */
#define ALI_WD_TIME_FACTOR 32787    /* (from seconds to ALi counter) */

static unsigned long wdt_is_open;
static char ali_expect_close;
static int wdt_run = 0;


static bool nowayout = WATCHDOG_NOWAYOUT;
module_param(nowayout, bool, 0);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(nowayout, "Watchdog cannot be stopped once started "
    "(default=" __MODULE_STRING(WATCHDOG_NOWAYOUT) ")");

static unsigned wdt_timeout = 60;
module_param(wdt_timeout, int, 0);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(wdt_timeout, "initial watchdog timeout (in seconds)");


static int alim6117_read(int index)
{
    outb(index, M6117_PORT_INDEX);
    return inb(M6117_PORT_DATA);
}

static void alim6117_write(int index, int data)
{
    outb(index, M6117_PORT_INDEX);
    outb(data, M6117_PORT_DATA);
}

static void alim6117_ulock_conf_register(void)
{
    alim6117_write(ALI_LOCK_REGISTER, 0xc5);
}

static void alim6117_lock_conf_register(void)
{
    alim6117_write(ALI_LOCK_REGISTER, 0x00);
}

static void alim6117_set_timeout(int time)
{
    u32 timeout_bits;

    timeout_bits = time * ALI_WD_TIME_FACTOR;
    alim6117_write(ALI_WDT_DATA0, timeout_bits & 0xff);
    alim6117_write(ALI_WDT_DATA1, (timeout_bits & 0xff00) >> 8);
    alim6117_write(ALI_WDT_DATA2, (timeout_bits & 0xff0000) >> 16);

    return;
}

static void alim6117_wdt_disable(void)
{
    int val = alim6117_read(ALI_WDT);

    val &= 0xbf;        /* 1011|1111 */
    alim6117_write(ALI_WDT, val);
}

static void alim6117_wdt_enable(void)
{
    int val = alim6117_read(ALI_WDT);

    val |= 0x40;        /* 0100|0000 */
    alim6117_write(ALI_WDT, val);
}

static void alim6117_wdt_signal_select(int signal)
{
    int val = alim6117_read(ALI_WDT_SELECT);

    val &= 0xf0;
    val |= signal;
    alim6117_write(ALI_WDT_SELECT, val);
}

static void ali_wdt_ping(void)
{
    int val;

    /* if no run, no ping; wdt start when ping it. */ 
    if (wdt_run) {
        alim6117_ulock_conf_register();
        val = alim6117_read(ALI_WDT);
        val &= ~0x40; /* 0100|0000 */
        alim6117_write(ALI_WDT, val);
        val |= 0x40;  /* 0100|0000 */
        alim6117_write(ALI_WDT, val);
        alim6117_lock_conf_register();
        /*
        printk(KERN_INFO OUR_NAME ": WDT ping...\n");
        */
    } else { 
        printk(KERN_WARNING OUR_NAME ": WDT is stopped\n");
    }
}

static void ali_wdt_start(void)
{
    alim6117_ulock_conf_register();
    alim6117_wdt_disable();
    alim6117_set_timeout(wdt_timeout);
    alim6117_wdt_signal_select(WDT_SIGNAL);
    alim6117_wdt_enable();
    alim6117_lock_conf_register();
    wdt_run = 1;
}

static void ali_wdt_stop(void)
{
    int val;
    if ( wdt_run ) {
        alim6117_ulock_conf_register();
        val = alim6117_read(ALI_WDT);
        val &= ~0x40;  /* 0100|0000 */
        alim6117_write(ALI_WDT, val);
        alim6117_lock_conf_register();
        wdt_run = 0;
        /*
        printk(KERN_INFO OUR_NAME ": WDT stop...\n");
        */
    }
}

/**
 *      ali_wdt_notify_sys:
 *      @this: our notifier block
 *      @code: the event being reported
 *      @unused: unused
 *
 *      Our notifier is called on system shutdowns. We want to turn the timer
 *      off at reboot otherwise the machine will reboot again during memory
 *      test or worse yet during the following fsck.
 *
 */

static int ali_wdt_notify_sys(struct notifier_block *this,
                  unsigned long code, void *unused)
{
    if (code == SYS_DOWN || code == SYS_HALT) {
        /* Turn the timer off */
        ali_wdt_stop();
    }
    return NOTIFY_DONE;
}

/**
 *      ali_write       -       writes to ALi watchdog
 *      @file: file handle to the watchdog
 *      @data: user address of data
 *      @len: length of data
 *      @ppos: pointer to the file offset
 *
 *      Handle a write to the ALi watchdog. Writing to the file pings
 *      the watchdog and resets it. Writing the magic 'V' sequence allows
 *      the next close to turn off the watchdog.
 */

static ssize_t ali_write(struct file *file, const char *data,
             size_t len, loff_t * ppos)
{
    /*  Can't seek (pwrite) on this device  */
    if (ppos != &file->f_pos)
        return -ESPIPE;

    /* Check if we've got the magic character 'V' and reload the timer */
    if (len) {
        size_t i;

        ali_expect_close = 0;

        /* scan to see whether or not we got the magic character */
        for (i = 0; i != len; i++) {
            u8 c;
            if (get_user(c, data + i))
                return -EFAULT;
            if (c == 'V')
                ali_expect_close = 42;
        }
        ali_wdt_ping();
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

/**
 *      ali_ioctl       -       handle watchdog ioctls
 *      @inode: inode of the device
 *      @file: file handle to the device
 *      @cmd: watchdog command
 *      @arg: argument pointer
 *
 *      Handle the watchdog ioctls supported by the ALi driver.
 */

static long ali_ioctl(struct file *file,
             unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{
    int options;

    static struct watchdog_info ident = {
        .options          = WDIOF_KEEPALIVEPING | WDIOF_SETTIMEOUT,
        .firmware_version = 0,
        .identity         = "ALi M6117 WDT",
    };

    switch (cmd) {
    case WDIOC_KEEPALIVE:
        ali_wdt_ping();
        return 0;
    case WDIOC_SETTIMEOUT:
        if (get_user(options, (int *) arg))
            return -EFAULT;
        if (options < 1 || options > 512)
            return -EFAULT;
        wdt_timeout = options;
        ali_wdt_start();
    case WDIOC_GETTIMEOUT:
        return put_user(wdt_timeout, (int *) arg);
    case WDIOC_GETSUPPORT:
        if (copy_to_user
            ((struct watchdog_info *) arg, &ident, sizeof(ident)))
            return -EFAULT;
        return 0;
    case WDIOC_GETSTATUS:
    case WDIOC_GETBOOTSTATUS:
        return put_user(0, (int *) arg);
    case WDIOC_SETOPTIONS:
        if (get_user(options, (int *) arg))
            return -EFAULT;
        if (options & WDIOS_DISABLECARD) {
            ali_wdt_stop();
            return 0;
        }
        if (options & WDIOS_ENABLECARD) {
            ali_wdt_start();
            return 0;
        }
        return -EINVAL;

    default:
        return -ENOTTY;

    }
}

/**
 *      ali_open        -       handle open of ali watchdog
 *      @inode: inode of device
 *      @file: file handle to device
 *
 *      Open the ALi watchdog device. Ensure only one person opens it
 *      at a time. Also start the watchdog running.
 */

static int ali_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    if(test_and_set_bit(0, &wdt_is_open))
                return -EBUSY;
    ali_wdt_start();

    return 0;
}

/**
 *      ali_release     -       close an ALi watchdog
 *      @inode: inode from VFS
 *      @file: file from VFS
 *
 *      Close the ALi watchdog device. Actual shutdown of the timer
 *      only occurs if the magic sequence has been set or nowayout is 
 *      disabled.
 */

static int ali_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    if (ali_expect_close == 42 && !nowayout) {
        ali_wdt_stop();
    } else {
        printk(KERN_CRIT OUR_NAME
               ": Unexpected close, not stopping watchdog!\n");
    }
    ali_expect_close = 0;
    clear_bit(0, &wdt_is_open);

    return 0;
}

static struct file_operations ali_fops = {
    .owner          = THIS_MODULE,
    .write          = ali_write,
    .unlocked_ioctl = ali_ioctl,
    .open           = ali_open,
    .release        = ali_release,
};

static struct miscdevice ali_miscdev = {
    .minor          = WATCHDOG_MINOR,
    .name           = "watchdog",
    .fops           = &ali_fops,
};

/*
 *   The WDT needs to learn about soft shutdowns in order to turn the
 *   timebomb registers off.
 */

static struct notifier_block ali_notifier = {
    .notifier_call = ali_wdt_notify_sys,
    .next          = NULL,
    .priority      = 0
};

static int __init alim6117_init(void)
{
    if (wdt_timeout < 1 || wdt_timeout > 512){
        printk(KERN_ERR OUR_NAME
               ": Timeout out of range (0 < wdt_timeout <= 512)\n");
        return -EIO;
    }

    if (misc_register(&ali_miscdev) != 0) {
        printk(KERN_ERR OUR_NAME
               ": cannot register watchdog device node.\n");
        return -EIO;
    }

    register_reboot_notifier(&ali_notifier);

    printk(KERN_INFO "WDT driver for ALi M6117 v(" 
           ALI_WDT_VERSION ") initialising.\n");

    return 0;
}

static void __exit alim6117_exit(void)
{
    misc_deregister(&ali_miscdev);
    unregister_reboot_notifier(&ali_notifier);

    ali_wdt_stop();     /* Stop the timer */
}

module_init(alim6117_init);
module_exit(alim6117_exit);

MODULE_AUTHOR("Federico Bareilles <fede@fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar>");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Driver for watchdog timer in ALi M6117 chip.");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_SUPPORTED_DEVICE("watchdog");
```

Comment: no idea about the rest of your question, but if you are pinging the loopback address `127.0.0.1`, you **should** use the `lo` loopback interface.

Comment: Ok, thanks for contributing, this answers part of my question so it is appreciated. Anyhow I do not think it is the solution to the main problem "having watchdog configured properly" since in the tons of guides that I've found online, all the authors just suggest to uncomment the line "/dev/watchdog" to enable the watchdog. This is another thing to be cleared: is it enough doing so in the /etc/watchdog.conf file or you are forced to enable some test (at least one) in that file and tell the watchdog what to watch at? (Thanks cas for making my post looking beautiful and readable!)